# Write XML elements into an .csv file

Tags: c#, xml

- First off I want to start with the fact that I'm a begginer at coding , especialy C#.
- Last year I've recived a program made in C# that could write XML elements to an excel file(at that point I didnt even know what kind of software).
- I've just edited the program so that I could get diffrent information out of the XML files, but I've hit a wall.
- I cannot seam to figure out how can I concatenate 2 identical elements of identical tags:

  ```
  <Person>
      <PERSONID>1</PERSONID>
      <FIRSTNAME>VICTOR</FIRSTNAME>
      <LASTNAME>DAN</LASTNAME>
  </Person>
  <Person>
      <PERSONID>2</PERSONID>
      <FIRSTNAME>JHON</FIRSTNAME>
      <LASTNAME>SMITH</LASTNAME>
  </Person>`
  ```

so that the output to be `DAN VICTOR/SMITH JHON`. Right now I've got just the first part

```
persoana = string.Concat(pp.LASTNAME, " ", pp.FIRSTNAME);
```

so when,

```
sout.WriteLine(string.Concat(new string[] { "\"", person, "\"" }));
```

kicks in, I get 2 rows in the .csv file for each person, but if I have multiple Tags with multiple Elements then the first one of the elemets get writen properly but the rest of them get updated with the last one , thats why I was thinkging if concatenating all of the elements.
 - Another problem I've encountered is when I'm facing with XMLs that do not have certain elements , then I get a `DBNull error`, Ive tryed to add an `if statement`

```
if (! DBNull.Value.Equals(lr.PARCELLEGALAREA.ToString())){
    parcellegalarea = lr.PARCELLEGALAREA.ToString(); 
}
```

but it doesnt do the trick. The debugger keeps on showing me:

```
[DebuggerNonUserCode]
[GeneratedCode("System.Data.Design.TypedDataSetGenerator", "4.0.0.0")]
public double PARCELLEGALAREA
{
    get
    {
        double item;
        try
        {
            item = (double)base[this.tableLand.PARCELLEGALAREAColumn];
        }
        catch (InvalidCastException invalidCastException)
        {
            throw new StrongTypingException("The value for column 'PARCELLEGALAREA' in table 'Land' is DBNull.", invalidCastException);
        }
        return item;
    }
    set
    {
        base[this.tableLand.PARCELLEGALAREAColumn] = value;
    }
}
```

- Here's a link to a simplified version of the program
  https://github.com/uZuRu17/Generare-Raport-CG
- And also a xml file
  https://github.com/uZuRu17/origina_cgxml/blob/master/example3.cgxml

Comment: Make `DBNull` value to string `ToString()` and then compare with `==` or `!=`.

Comment: One of the first tings Ive tried was ``if (lr.PARCELLEGALAREA.ToString()) == DBNull.ToString())`` and ``if (lr.PARCELLEGALAREA.ToString()) == DBNull)`` but thats not a valid sintax. Could you be a little more specific? Also, thank you for your time

Comment: To verify that object is `DBNull` you have to compare it without `ToString()` - e.g. `if (lr.PARCELLEGALAREA == DBNull.Value)`. The other method is to convert to string, then compare with empty string, not `DBNull`.

Comment: If you're looking for null specifically: `if (lr.PARCELLEGALAREA == DBNull.Value)`. If you want to treat null and an empty string the same way: `if (lr.PARCELLEGALAREA.ToString() == string.Empty)`.

Comment: The debbuger keeps on showing me    System.Data.StrongTypingException: 'The value for column 'PARCELLEGALAREA' in table 'Land' is DBNull.'

Comment: `if ( string.IsNullOrEmpty( lr.PARCELLEGALAREA.ToString() ) )`.

Comment: Ive tried out all your sugestions, they are all correct syntaxes but they do not work for some reason, my gues is that its something with the cgxml.cs file, I think I need to figure out whats with the exceptions...

Comment: If downloaded your project and got it running. Usually you use persoana = string.Join(",", new string[] {pp.LASTNAME, pp.FIRSTNAME});  For other issue try : item = (object)base[this.tableLand.CADGENNOColumn] == DBNull.Value ? string.Empty : (string)base[this.tableLand.CADGENNOColumn];  If double is going to be null use double?  The question mark will allow either a double or null value.

Comment: Ive repaced ``persoana = string.Concat(pp.LASTNAME, " ", pp.FIRSTNAME);`` with ``persoana = string.Join(",", new string[] {pp.LASTNAME, pp.FIRSTNAME});`` and now instead of ``DAN MARIA`` I get ``DAN,MARIA`` , and for the second problem Ive repaced ``item = (double)base[this.tableLand.PARCELLEGALAREAColumn];`` with your code and..  ''Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'double''' .  This is getting a little frustrating as this is not the first time Im unable to integrate the answers to my projects, but oh well I gues it will fill me with joy when I will finish this

Comment: Did anyone get problems on getting the project running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

be sure you don't have copies of the same cgxml in another folder inside the folder you select - thats the only case that made duplicte rows for the same person with me with your code because i had two copies of your example3.cgxml one in the parent directory and another one in subdirectory folder and i select the parent directory

You can use only files in your current directory by modifying this line

```
FileInfo[] files = (new DirectoryInfo(this.folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath))
.GetFiles("*.cgxml", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
```

instead of:

```
FileInfo[] files = (new DirectoryInfo(this.folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath))
.GetFiles("*.cgxml", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

According to your request you want to have row for each possible pacrel / person combination so your foreach percon loop need to be neasted into foreach parcel loop like this

```
foreach (CGXML.ParcelRow pr in fisier.Parcel)
                {
                    cat = pr.USECATEGORY;
                    measarea = pr.MEASUREDAREA.ToString();


                    foreach (CGXML.PersonRow pp in fisier.Person)
                    {
                        persoana = string.Concat(pp.LASTNAME, " ", pp.FIRSTNAME);
                        sout.WriteLine(string.Concat(new string[] { "\"", cadgenno.ToString(), "\",\"", sector, "\",\"", persoana, "\",\"", parcellegalarea.ToString(), "\",\"", measarea.ToString(), "\",\"", cat, "\"" }));

                    }
                }
```

and the output will be:

ID SECTOR  Person  ID Area Parcel Area Parcel Category

1   36  DAN VICTOR  7500    7000    A

1   36  DAN MARIA   7500    7000    A

1   36  DAN VICTOR  7500    500 F

1   36  DAN MARIA   7500    500 F

Comment: Duplicationg xml files might happen only if some1 makes a copy of the XML folder in side it or make a edited version of an XML file in the same folder , Im mainly the only 1 who changes them and I do that on my PC not on the server so that wount be a problem. But thank you for the reminder I will add this to the notes so I can modify it later on if someone needs it that way.

Comment: I tried your program and produces 1 name per row except for that case and it didn't produce null exception too-so see whats the difference and check your server you can send another file that produce the problem so we can test it, thank you

Comment: I have 2 Parcels and 2 Persons in the XML file, the tabel output looks like this : Person 2 , Parcel 1 / Person 2 , Parcel 2 . Because the the Person is updated with the last Person. So Im looking for a difrent aproach , but I dont know how to make it so that I will get un output tat looks like : Person 1 | Person 2 , Parcel 1 / Person 1 | Person 2 , Parcel 2